# Find the nearest time from list of array

Tags: php

I am looking for two values in an array:

- last array value from 08/29/2013 08:00 to 08/29/2013 13:00
- first array value from 08/29/2013 12:00 to 08/29/2013 17:00

Here is the array:

```
$dates = array(
    '08/29/2013 08:00',
    '08/29/2013 08:10',
    '08/29/2013 08:11',
    '08/29/2013 12:20',
    '08/29/2013 12:21',
    '08/29/2013 12:21',
    '08/29/2013 17:30',
); // etc.
```

Comment: That last entry btw, doesn't need a comma.

Comment: Will there be multiple days in the array?

Comment: @Fred -ii-: it's a good practice to place it there

Comment: @zerkms I've seen it so many times where having a comma in a final entry, caused havoc. Now I'm really confused. Kind of a "darned if I don't and darned if I do".

Comment: its optional, like sarcasm :-)

Comment: What do you mean "last value around"? What is the intended outcome here?

Comment: @Fred -ii-: it's mostly about SCMs: 1. When you add another item and see a diff - one line would be changed 2. When 2 people added another item and you're resolving conflict - you shouldn't be aware of adding another comma after merge

Comment: @zerkms Thanks, I've made a note of it. I appreciate the info.

Comment: @zerkms Is that a PHP thing or something? Because I've never heard of coding for SCMs being important. I know in JavaScript, that extra comma can cause problems in some versions of IE for Objects, or create an extra undefined item in an Array. I'd rather avoid both of those, especially not just to please SCM workflow

Comment: @Ian: it's probably suitable for any language that allows trailing comma safe. So I follow that practice for php and don't for js (for syntax reasons)

Answer (score 1):

One of the best ways to compare times is to convert your strings to times using `strtotime()`.

```
// Original array of date strings
$dates = array(
  '08/29/2013 08:00',
  '08/29/2013 08:10',
  '08/29/2013 08:11',
  '08/29/2013 12:20',
  '08/29/2013 12:21',
  '08/29/2013 12:21',
  '08/29/2013 17:30',
);

// Make a new array of time stamps based on your strings
$dates_dt = array();
foreach($dates as $date)
  $dates_dt[] = strtotime($date);

// Same idea with the dates you want to look at
$date_last1 = strtotime('08/29/2013 08:00');
$date_last2 = strtotime('08/29/2013 13:00');
$date_first1 = strtotime('08/29/2013 12:00');
$date_first2 = strtotime('08/29/2013 17:00');
```

Here's the magic - some pretty simple functions that return the closest date before (or the first entry), and the closest after (or the last) in your array.

```
function dateBefore($date, $dateArray){
  $prev = $dateArray[0];
  foreach( $dateArray as $d ){
      if( $d >= $date )
          return date("Y-m-d H:i", $prev);
      $prev = $d;
  }
}

function dateAfter($date, $dateArray){
  foreach( $dateArray as $d ){
      if( $d > $date )
          return date("Y-m-d H:i", $d);
  }
  return date("Y-m-d H:i", end($dateArray));
}

echo dateBefore($date_last1, $dates_dt); // Outputs: 2013-08-29 08:00
echo dateBefore($date_last2, $dates_dt); // Outputs: 2013-08-29 12:21

echo dateAfter($date_first1, $dates_dt); // Outputs: 2013-08-29 12:20
echo dateAfter($date_first2, $dates_dt); // Outputs: 2013-08-29 17:30
```

http://codepad.org/cBYPuowt

**Note**
Probably a good idea to sort the array of times as well so they're for sure in order.

```
foreach($dates as $date)
  $dates_dt[] = strtotime($date);

// Add sort here
sort($dates_dt);
```

http://codepad.org/jZPIEeJS

Answer (score 0):

You can convert all of the string timestamps to long values (milliseconds since 1970 epoch). Then just calculate the delta for relevant values (greater than 08/29/2013 08:00, for instance) compared to the upper limit (08/29/2013 13:00, for instance). The smallest delta is the closest to the upper limit. The greatest delta is furthest.

This is how you calculate the seconds since epoch: http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$nearest = $dates[0];
$now = time();
for ($i = 0; $i < count($dates); $i++) {
  $date = $dates[$i];
  $timestamp = strtotime($date);
  if (abs(strtotime($date) - $now) < abs(strtotime($nearest) - $now))
    $nearest = $date;
}
echo $nearest;
```